# How do I make an array of only Strings from a txt file with Strings and doubles?

Tags: java, string, file, double

Heres the txt file: http://txt.do/5w3em

I just need the Strings (EXCLUDING THE COMMENTED OUT ONES), the M's and B's, all on separate lines from the text file and none of the doubles. How do I make an array list to store them all?
I tried this

```
List<String> trainingDatasetStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
    while(inFile.hasNextLine()){
        String line = inFile.nextLine();
        String[] words = line.split(",");
        for(int i = 11; i < words.length; i++)
        trainingDatasetStrings.add(words[i]);
    }
```

But it wont help.

Comment: Well they all look like they can be converted into an `Object`... With those fields. but a simple `scan.nextLine().split(",");` would suffice in splitting it up

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try something like this:

```
List<String> trainingDatasetStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
while(inFile.hasNextLine()){
    String line = inFile.nextLine().trim();
    // Skip past blank file lines and file lines that start with "//" 
    if (!line.startsWith("//") && !line.equals("")) {
        String[] words = line.split(",");
        trainingDatasetStrings.add(words[words.length - 1]);
    }
}
```

That is of course if all you want are the B's and M's.